# ¿Como puedo integrar Admob a una aplicación Android generada con Dukescript?

Tags: java, dukescript, admob

¿Cómo agrego la funcionalidad de mostrar publicidad de `AdMob` a un proyecto android de [dukescript](/questions/tagged/dukescript) creado con [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans)?

Digamos por ejemplo que seleccioné android en el ejemplo del [hola mundo](https://github.com/GeertjanWielenga/DukeScriptSamples/tree/master/KnockoutLiveExamples/01-HelloWorld/HelloWorld), y que la aplicación ya está publicada y que ya tengo unos espacios creados desde el sitio de admob.

Para este ejemplo me gustaría decir que sus `Ad unit ID` son

```
ca-app-pub-99999999999999999/9999999999
```

correspondiente a una publicidad `interstitial` (las que muestran animaciones en pantalla completa) y

```
ca-app-pub-9999999999999999/9999999998
```

correspondiente a un baner.

Hasta donde sé, no se pueden mostrar únicamente con [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), se deben agregar jars a las librerías antes de compilar (ya sea la de `admob SDK` o la de `Google Play Services`).

Answer (score 1):

Los amigos de `Dukescript` están actualmente trabajando en una API oficial para hacerlo más sencillo.

He visto que preguntaste en StackOverflow la misma pregunta, de hecho quien te responde es una persona de `Dukescript` y esa es la forma actual para poder implementar anuncios `AdMob` en en una aplicación `Android` creada con `Dukescript`.

[**How to integrate admob to Dukescript generated apk?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808674/how-to-integrate-admob-to-dukescript-generated-apk/33856936#33856936)

¿Deseas que te ayudemos con la traducción?

Comment: yo habia visto esa respuesta pero me daba cosa mandarlo al sitio en ingles y no soy partidario de traducir jaja, me parece super correcta la forma de plantearlo -> Deseas te ayudemos con la traducción, de todas formas creo que la pregunta si no recuerdo mal es del mismo usuario +10 haha

Comment: Gracias, Mr. Epple me escribió un correo hace unas horas para avisarme. Cuando lo pregunté aquí, había podido integrar él jar, pero no se mostraba la publicidad porque no la hallaba en la SD, así que la solución aún no estaba completa.